# Merge multiple lines into one using Sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I am very new to Sublime Text and I am sure this is a naive question. Watching the Multiple line selection at http://www.sublimetext.com/ (2/6 slide).  Absolutely love it.

I understand that <kbd>Ctrl (Cmd)</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> "multiple-selects" so that we could do the edit simultaneously.  However, in the demo, they also merge all the lines into 1 single line. What is the shortcut for that?
I used <kbd>**Ctrl**</kbd>+<kbd>**J**</kbd> but it just deletes once and not all the occurrences of new line.

I use TextPad and use Find/Replace `\n` with an empty space. But it seems that the person giving the demo uses some kind of shortcut.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I think that, in the demo, he presses <kbd>Del</kbd>, with the cursor at the end of the line, in multiple selection. This way the `\n` is removed in every selected line.

Comment: LOL. You are right. I just had my wordwrap "on" and was bothered.

Comment: This is clever, but adds whitespace when lines are uneven in length. The Command/Ctrl + J solution is better.

Comment: -1 Doing this with thousands of lines selected will kill your CPU and memory

Answer (score 285):

A single command shortcut for merging multiple lines into 1 is "join lines".

- <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> on the Mac to join lines.
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> on Windows
- Edit > Lines > Join Lines

**Important note**: This keyboard shortcut changed in versions of sublime text released after around mid-2021. For *older* versions, use <kbd>Command</kbd>  + <kbd>J</kbd>, or <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>.

Another approach is seen in the demo animations on [sublimetext.com](http://www.sublimetext.com/).  Using multiple selections, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> is used to split a selection into lines, and each line is then edited simultaneously.  <kbd>end</kbd> + <kbd>del</kbd> will then remove all line breaks.  This can be seen in slide 2/6 at http://sublimetexttips.com/7-handy-text-manipulation-tricks-sublime-text-2/

Comment: And if you're looking for it in the the menu's, its under Edit > Lines > Join Lines

Comment: Thanks. cmd+J is working properly in Mac Sublime version. It join the lines with a space. Like:
1. Hello 
2. world

after cmd + J it becomes:
1. Hello world

Comment: Probably it is obvious, but still - you can select any part of the text and use this combination applying to the selected text.

Comment: Cool - reminding "J" vi command. Sublime authors are really smart!

Comment: **Note:** CTRL + J / Command + J keeps the whitespace at the end of each line into the joined line, which is not obvious at first sight. Coming around that, the second suggestion is a better choice.

Comment: Recent sublime version on mac has shortcut command+shift+j.

Answer (score 35):

`ctrl+a` and `ctrl+j` seems working on sublime text 3.

Answer (score 7):

Editing

join    Joins the following line to the current line, replacing all in between whitespace with a single space

http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/commands

Go to edit option in menu, Edit -> line -> join lines

Answer (score 6):

Select the lines you want to merge and press `Ctrl + j` and if you want to make all file in 1 line then do `Ctrl + a` and `Ctrl + j`.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to merge lines into one line that will also remove the starting, and ending space from the line, the following regex should work:

```
Find What: ^\s*(.+)\s*\n
Replace With: \1
```

Answer (score 1):

Sublime Text 3 for Mac:

cmd + j no longer works and is now `CMD + SHIFT + J`

Answer (score 0):

`Join lines` is a good command, but it adds spaces between the merged lines. To merge lines without spacing, the easiest way appears to be the following:

1. `Find -> Replace` (Command+Option+F on Mac)
2. `Ctrl+Enter` to enter newline to the `Find What` field.
3. Don't enter anything into the `Replace With` field.
4. Press `Replace All`.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using a regex approach in Sublime Text 3, as follows:

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> (in Windows) to show the "Find and Replace" dialog at the bottom.
- In the "Find" field, use `$\n\s*` (end of line, carriage return and any arbitrary number of spaces following, including zero, which should be at the beginning of the next line).
- The "Replace" field should be empty.
- Hit "Replace All" or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

This should do the trick!